# $f: GL(2, \mathbb{R}) \to GL(2, \mathbb{R)}, \ A\mapsto A^{-1}$. Looking for $df(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f: GL(2, \mathbb{R}) \to GL(2, \mathbb{R)}, \ A\mapsto A^{-1}$

What's $df(A) (\in linear(\mathbb{R^4,\mathbb{R^4)\cong \mathbb{R}^{4\times4}}}$?

If I look at $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ as a vector:

$\begin{pmatrix}A_{11}\\A_{12}\\A_{21}\\A_{22}\end{pmatrix}$

Then $f(A)=\frac{1}{A_{11}A_{22}-A_{A12}A_{21}} \begin{pmatrix}A_{22}\\-A_{21}\\-A_{12}\\A_{11}\end{pmatrix}$.

So $\frac{\partial f(A)}{\partial A_{11}}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\\frac{-A_{22}}{(A_{11}A_{22}-A_{12}A_{21})^2}\end{pmatrix}$

$\frac{\partial f(A)}{\partial A_{12}}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\\frac{-A_{21}}{(A_{11}A_{22}-A_{12}A_{21})^2}\\0\end{pmatrix}$

$\frac{\partial f(A)}{\partial A_{21}}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\\frac{-A_{12}}{(A_{11}A_{22}-A_{12}A_{21})^2}\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$

$\frac{\partial f(A)}{\partial A_{22}}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{-A_{11}}{(A_{11}A_{22}-A_{12}A_{21})^2}\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$

So is $df(A)$ the row-vector consisting of this 4 matrices?

Comment: Your derivatives all look wrong to me. Quotient rule?

Comment: Yes I messed that up

Answer (score 5):

You're not wrong(at least in principle, I didn't check the calculations), but you can also consider that if $g(A)=A$ is the identity map on the matrix space $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, then the product
$f(A)g(A) = I$, so that by product rule,
$$0 = d(fg)(A)H = (df(A)H) g(A) + f(A)(dg(A)H) = df(A) HA +A^{-1}H,$$
giving
$$ df(A) H= -A^{-1}H A^{-1}.$$

Comment: (+1) for appealing to a basis-independent argument. Alternatively, one can extract $(df)_A(H)$ from the expansion $$f(A+H)=(A(I+A^{-1}H))^{-1}=(I+A^{-1}H)A^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-A^{-1}H)^nA^{-1}$$ which holds for $H$ with sufficiently small matrix norm.

Comment: @SangchulLee that computes all other derivatives as well!

Comment: @CalvinKhor I got another question. How can I argue that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuously differentiable? For $f$: Does this follow from the leibniz-formula which states that the determinant is a polynomial and therefore $C^\infty?$ Is that enough? And  $f^{-1}$ is continuously differentiable because $f$ is continuously differentiable and bijective?

Comment: @user586087 yes, the components of $f$ are rational functions of the components of $A$ where their denominators do not vanish on the domain. by $f^{-1}$ do you mean the inverse map? Because the inverse matrix of the inverse matrix is the original matrix, ie $f=f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$df(A)$ is a linear application from $M(2,\mathbb R)$ into $M(2,\mathbb R)$, where $M(2,\mathbb R)$ is the vector space of $2 \times 2$ real matrices. If you denote an element (a matrix) of $M(2,\mathbb R)$ as a vector with $4$ dimensions, then $df(A)$ is the $4 \times 4$ matrix whose columns are the vectors you computed.

Comment: This makes no sense, since $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is not a vector space.

Comment: You’re right... a typo. Replaced linear group $GL$ with $M$ the matrix vector space.